# Pass data from ASP.NET Webmethod to Angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angular, data-binding

Hello Stackoverflowers, 
Apologies if this is duplicate, I really tried to find a simple answer for this, but I couldn't.

I need to pass some data from **ASP.NET Webmethod** to my Angular 2 class.
I'm starting off with a very simple string "hello".
How can I use the server side `Get()` method to populate the `value` value ?

My .NET server side code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Get()
{
   return "Hello Koby";
}
```

My Angular 2 code (Very simplified):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'log',
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/Angular2/templates/log.html'
})

export class Log {    
    private http;
    value = ? // <----- This should come from the server
}
```

Being new to Angular 2, I can accept solutions, workarounds or curse words.

Thanks.